# How to call angular component at run time?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7

I am working on angular 7 application and I have one requirement :

In my angular application I have number of components like componentOne, componentTwo, componentThree, etc. In main component (Main) I have an array like ['componentTwo', 'componentFive'], so I want loop through this array and call the corresponding component.

So If I want to call only these components then I will place the code like this :

```
<div>
   <componentTwo></componentTwo>
   <componentFive></componentFive>
</div>
```

But the issue is that I don't know that which component will come in the array. So is there any way to call components dynamically?

I tried this but it didn't work :

```
<div>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let componentName of componentArray">
      <{{componentName}}></{{componentName}}>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Any kind of help is appreciable, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe listen to an output from another component and handle the event in the typescipt file.  Please see code below.  I hope this helps.

main.html

```
<div (updateComponentArray)="updateComponentArray($event)">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let componentName of componentArray">
        < {{componentName}}></ {{componentName}}>
    </ng-container>

</div>
```

main.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  componentArray: string[];
  updateComponentArray(components:string[]) {
    this.componentArray = components;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic compenents. At this example the ErrorDialogComponent is created dynamically in the showErrorAlert function. Notice the use of createComponent and of ComponentFactoryResolver. You can also set the dynamic component's data using its instance.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ProductsService } from './products.service';
import { ErrorDialogComponent } from '@app/shared/error-dialog/error-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.scss']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('errorPlaceHolder', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) errorPlaceHolder: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
  }

  private showErrorAlert(errorMessage: string) {
    this.showError = true;
    const errorComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ErrorDialogComponent);
    this.errorPlaceHolder.clear();
    const errorCompnent = this.errorPlaceHolder.createComponent(errorComponentFactory);
    errorCompnent.instance.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    errorCompnent.instance.dismiss.subscribe(() => {
      this.errorPlaceHolder.clear();
    });
  }
}
```